# Python integer * float = NotImplemented

Tags: python, operator-keyword

So I was messing around writing a vector class when I discovered this interesting fact.

```
>>> e = int(3)
>>> e.__mul__(3.0)
NotImplemented
```

Can anyone explain why this is and subsequently, how to fix my vector class?

```
class Vector(tuple):
    '''A vector representation.'''
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        super(Vector, self).__init__(iterable)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(map(operator.add, self, other))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(map(operator.sub, self, other))

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return Vector(map(scalar.__mul__, self))

    def __rmul__(self, scalar):
         return Vector(map(scalar.__mul__, self))

    def __div__(self, scalar):
        return Vector(map(scalar.__rdiv__, self))
```

EDIT: To be a little more clear:

```
>>> a = Vector([10, 20])
>>> a
(10, 20)
>>> b = a / 2.0
>>> b
(5.0, 10.0)
>>> 2 * b
(NotImplemented, NotImplemented)
```

Comment: What do you need fixed in your `Vector` class?

Comment: What has the Vector class  to do with the two-line example???

Comment: Well, what's WRONG with your vector class?

Comment: Don't have full anwser for you but, i think that multiplying integer and float, will trigger float's __mul__ method, as python always courses variable toward more complicated in such operations.

Comment: Also consider using `numpy.array`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because when you do  `3 * 3.0` the interpreter is calling `(3.0).__rmul__(3)` after realizing that `(3).__mul__(3.0)` is not implemented

Float's `__mul__` and `__rmul__` functions do cast integers to float but that should not happen with the int class.

Otherwise `3 * 3.5` would be `9` instead of `10.5`

**The second question:**

Why do people insist on `map` when list comprehensions (and generator expressions) are much better?

try that:

```
def __mul__(self, scalar):
    return Vector(scalar * j for j in self)
```

You should do that to every other function on the class.

Comment: It was just a lack of thinking. I somewhat recently discovered functional programming and have simply been in the mindset to map / reduce everything. Totally with you on the change though.

Comment: @Ceasar It's Ok, but just keep in mind that comprehensions are more readable (99.99% of the time) and are the ultimate replace for map/filter. Reduce shall never be used (in Python)!